# Create Docker-Machine without re-provisioning Docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have an existing AWS EC2 instance with docker already provisioned on it. I would like to import this existing host to allow Docker Machine to manage this locally.

To do this, so far I have been using the [generic](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/) driver. But as you can see in the documentation, it re-provisions docker every time, thereby bringing down my running containers. The [AWS](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/) driver does not seem to have an option to do this either.

So how can I add an existing host locally without re-provisioning docker or bringing down my containers?

Comment: Maybe it is enough to add that docker host to an existing Docker swarm? I dont think you can turn it on the fly to machine managed.

Comment: On the other hand: if it hurts you to retart the docker containers you might need to change your landscape to make it less stateful and more resilient anyway.

Comment: you're right it might make more sense to change my landscape. Was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to change too much